# How do I send a group SMS with google hangouts?

Tags: sms

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 on Verizon if that matters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. In Hangouts start a new conversation by going to the Messages tab and pressing on the "+" button on the top-right.
2. Select the first contact.  This should open the Hangout conversation screen:
   [[image: conversation screen]

   <sub>click for larger image</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVkCo.jpg)
3. Tap the "Anyone else?" button next to the first participant on the top row.  This brings up the "New group conversation" screen:
   [[image: New group conversation]

   <sub>click for larger image</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxj7m.jpg)
4. Add more contacts you wish to be included in the group conversation by tapping on their name, or typing in their name:
   [[image: Add more contacts]

   <sub>click for larger image</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5L1t.jpg)
5. Press the OK button.  This opens up the actual group conversation with all the selected participants.  You should see "Send to group" in the typing area, signifying that you are starting a group Hangout:
   [[image]

   <sub>click for larger image</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScCVl.jpg)

You can also turn an existing single-participant hangout into a group chat.  Just open the existing chat, tap on Menu button, select "New group conversation" and continue on from step 3 above.

Now messages you send and receive will be shared with all participants.

Comment: This did not answer the OP's question. The question was to send a group SMS message via the hangouts app. Not a Group Hangout message. I would like an answer to the OP's question as well.

Comment: Same here. I find it... not so convenient.